# phpunit fail using phing

Tags: php, jenkins, phing

I'm using jenkins to build and test my php application, for the build I use phing because it's written in PHP (instead of ant..)

here is a part of my build file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project name" default="target">
  ...
  <target name="phpcs-ci" description="Find coding standard violations using PHP_CodeSniffer creating a log file for the continuous integration server">
  <exec executable="phpcs" output="/dev/null">
     <arg value="--report=checkstyle" />
     <arg value="--report-file=${project.basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml" />
     <arg value="--standard=${project.basedir}/build/phpcs.xml" />
     <arg path="${project.basedir}/src" />
  </exec>
  </target>
  ...
  <!-- Kick off phpunit -->
  <target name="phpunit" description="Run tests described in phpunit.xml file.">
    <exec logoutput="true" command="phpunit" escape="false" /> 
  </target>
...
</project>
```

The build shows this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Class PHPUnitTestRunner contains 1 abstract method
>   and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining
>   methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest) in
>   /usr/share/php/phing/tasks/ext/phpunit/PHPUnitTestRunner.php on line
>   322

Any idea how solve this problem ?

Comment: I've undeleted and re-opened this - please can you improve the question a bit more as well as share your answer though.

Comment: in fact, the fix was committed, so just update phing ! https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/commit/ecd51b6b6e62fd97f27ce3838f84389173b1934e